# Can't find the value CanCollide on object

Tags: lua, roblox

so I have recently started coding in LUA and I have been stuck on finding some objects.

My problem is to modify value "CanCollide" on the following Path : "`game:GetService("Workspace").Map.Game.Tiles`" but  it has two different paths underneath "Tiles" which are "Left" and "Right", so what I tried is to get the value `CanCollide` from `Tiles` and not from `/Tiles/Left/Tile2` and it did not work, as I thought.
The thing is, that I've been looking for lots of methods to get every `CanCollide` value from Tiles but I think that it does find nothing. I also have tried a for loop : `for i,v in pairs(game:GetService("Workspace").Map.Game.Tiles)` to get every "CanCollide" value. My point is to get every "CanCollide" value on every "Tiles" and not to type every single tile path to disable the value, like : `if game:GetService("Workspace").Map.Game.Tiles/Left/Tile1.CanCollide == false then` `if game:GetService("Workspace").Map.Game.Tiles/Left/Tile2.CanCollide == false then` etc,
I wrote this script but of course, nothing shows up

```
    for i,v in pairs(game:GetService("Workspace").Map.Game.Tiles.Left.Tile1) do
if v.CanCollide == true then 
v.BrickColor = BrickColor.Black
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through just 1 object, `game.Workspace.Map.Game.Tiles.Left.Tile1`

If it is a model, you can do:

`for i,v in pairs(game:GetService("Workspace").Map.Game.Tiles.Left.Tile1:GetChildren()) do`,
then check if each child is a part with the IsA() method and set the collisions appropriately like so:

```
if v:IsA("Part") then
    if v.CanCollide == true then 
        v.BrickColor = BrickColor.Black
    end
end
```

This will leave you with:

```
for i,v in pairs(game:GetService("Workspace").Map.Game.Tiles.Left.Tile1:GetChildren()) do
    if v:IsA("Part") then
        if v.CanCollide == true then 
            v.BrickColor = BrickColor.Black
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answer :) So can I just do `for i,v in pairs(game:GetService("Workspace").Map.Game.Tiles.Left:GetChildren()) do
    if v:IsA("Part") then
        if v.CanCollide == true then 
            v.BrickColor = BrickColor.Black
        end
    end
end` to get every children from Tile ? Or should I make a loop throught "/Tiles" to get each tile 1 per 1 ? Have a great day :)

Comment: Depends. If /Tiles is a directory with models, loop through /Left. If its a folder with parts, loop through /Titles.